# PHP: One page for all users VS one page per user?

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication

Well guys, thank you alot for your answers, I will change the question a bit to go right to the point:
Let's assume a php website has 1 million known users (and this is the final and limited number):Is it better to program one profile page for all the users or to create a physical php page for each user (I wish to know the technical differences: speed, space, treatments...etc.)
I only want to know the difference
thank you again

Comment: A login page for each user is a chicken-and-egg problem. How do you know the user identity (to display the user-specific login page) before they authenticate themselves in the login page?

Comment: right, let's say it's an exe program that runs the php to retrieve data, but let's say we can know each user, which method will be better? thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "One page for each user"? One login page for each user? That doesn't make sense, a login page is for identifying a user (not really, but very simplified). So you should have one login page, where your users can authenticate with :) Or do you mean one php file for each user (profile)? That doesn't make sense and isn't scalable, so you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I changed my question for better understanding...

Answer (score 1):

Having separate page for each user will is worst thing to implement(Again it depends, in very few scenario you need to implement different page for each user) As is it was already told by Florian that it isn't scale-able .

You should go with

> http://example.com?user=user1.

and your statement '*each user can only access specific options, that are initially programmed in his particular page*'
For achieving this you need to use **Role Based authorization** on each functionality page you have on your website.  And you can mask the url using `http.access`.

Comment: why is that the "worst thing"?
thank you alot
I changed my question for better understanding...

Answer (score -1):

Why you ought to have one different page for each user?

Comment: well, so each user can only access specific options, that are initially programmed in his particular page,..
Anyway I'm still asking so you can say I want to learn the technical difference between the two methods, that's all

Comment: You should ask questions as a comment ;)